# How to successfully request permissions with jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I've created the most default app, and am trying to request the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission. However I am unable to trigger the dialog that's meant to show during runtime, and instead it immediately results in `PERMISSION DENIED` without showing anything.

What's the canonical way with an off-the-shelve android project to request these runtime permissions?

I've added androidx.fragment, androidx.activity and the accompanist dependency. There are no errors reported in the log, and the log lines you see in the code get reported accordingly.

Here my (current) code for reference

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private val requestPermissionLauncher =
        registerForActivityResult(
            ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()
        ) { isGranted: Boolean ->
            if (isGranted) {
                Log.e("activity", "granted")
            } else {
                Log.e("activity", "not granted")
            }
        }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyApplicationTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Greeting("Android", {
                        requestPermissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String, callback: () -> Unit, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {

    Box {
        Button(
            onClick = { callback() }
        ) {
            Text(
                "hello"
            )
        }
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun GreetingPreview(onClick: () -> Unit = {}) {
    MyApplicationTheme {
        Greeting("Android", onClick)
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is my complete blog on requesting permission in ```Jetpack Compose```. https://medium.com/@chiragthummar16/requesting-permission-jetpack-compose-the-complete-guide-03e8aaa1f4a0

Comment: What version of Android is the device you are testing on? That permission doesn't exist on [Android 13 and higher](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13#granular-media-permissions).

Comment: yikes - that's the issue. I didn't realise targeting android 34 means android 14. Thanks, you saved me a few hours here